# Declare/ Set Variables in PL/SQL Oracle 11

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a column that has ID set as year and month together.

For Example: ID: 201706 where '2017' is the year and '06' is month and the month and year changes as new data gets added to the table.

I want to set a variable so that the where clause in my query pulls data from current month's data. Also want to compare that to last year/month's amount.

How do i write a query declaring yearmonth(201706) in the same column?

Comment: How is "the current month's data" defined? Is there a column? What is the datatype? Does this have anything to do with how to declare/set variables in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you need result to be retrieve just from one row

```
   DECLARE
     l_month NUMBER; // declaring variable of type number;
    BEGIN 
      SELECT SUBSTR(column, 5) //will return last 2 digits, which is month
      INTO l_month  // getting value from select clause
      FROM table
      WHERE ...;
    END;
```

If you need retrieve multiple rows

```
 DECLARE
      TYPE l_month_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER;  // collection of type NUMBER
      l_month l_month_type; // instance of collection
    BEGIN 
      SELECT SUBSTR(column, 5) //will return last 2 digits, which is month
      BULK COLLECT INTO l_month // getting data into collection
      FROM table
      WHERE ...;
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this below snippet helps.

```
WITH TEMP_DATA AS
  ( SELECT '201601' ID,100 QTY FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201601' ID,200 QTY FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201602' ID,101 QTY FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201603' ID,102 QTY FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201604' ID,103 QTY FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201605' ID,104 QTY FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT TO_DATE(ID,'YYYYMM'),
  COUNT(1)
FROM TEMP_DATA
GROUP BY TO_DATE(ID,'YYYYMM')
ORDER BY TO_DATE(ID,'YYYYMM');

-----------------------Comparing data Reporting Purpose--------------------------------

SELECT *
FROM
  (WITH TEMP_DATA AS
  ( SELECT '201601' ID,100 QTY FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201601' ID,200 QTY FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201602' ID,101 QTY FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201603' ID,102 QTY FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201604' ID,103 QTY FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201605' ID,104 QTY FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT ID,QTY FROM TEMP_DATA
  ) PIVOT (COUNT(QTY) FOR ID IN ('201601','201602','201603','201604','201605') );
```